# java 8 i/o stream application

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a CSV file below and I wrote the method below to parse the file.

```
"PRODUCT_NAME","PRODUCT_CATEGORY","SALES_PRICE"
"Hair Gel","Beauty",6.99 
"Scotch tape","Office Supply",2.99
"Office Chair","Office Supply",134.99
```

My code:

```
public static void ReadFile(String path, Map<String, List<Double>> db){
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))){
        String line;
        if((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            //this line is the heading..and needed to be skipped
        }
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] keys = line.split(",");
            keys[1] = keys[1].replace("\"", "");
            if(db.containsKey(keys[1])){
                List<Double> list = db.get(keys[1]);
                list.add(Double.valueOf(keys[2]));
                db.put(keys[1], list);
            }
            else{
                List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(Double.valueOf(keys[2]));
                db.put(keys[1],list);
            }
        }

    }catch(IOException e){}
}
```

It works fine in parsing the file but my main question is how could the above method be written taking advantage of java8 stream and lambda functionality?

Comment: Have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @khelwood, I think this question is a way to avoid answering people's questions. Java8 is still relatively new for most developers. I showed how to do it in java7 and my question is for the experts in the community to point me to how to get it also done in java8. Except you want me to write down jargons all in the name of trying, then yeah, I tried and couldn't get it solved and that was why I turned to SO.

Comment: No, the way I avoid answering people's questions is just by not answering them. Posting comments is a way to try to improve questions.

Comment: Why everybody wants to parse CSV manually? There are many caveats, in particular you cannot just split by comma. And there are ready well-tested free libraries available. Why not using them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve a Stream over the lines of the file with [`Files.lines(path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) (and you can get a `Path` with [`Paths.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-)). The header line is skipped with [`skip(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-), then each line is split around `","`.

Finally, the Stream element are grouped by the first element of the keys (with quotes removed) and the values are mapped to the `Double` value of the second element of the keys and collected into a `List`. The group operation is done with the [`groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector: the classifier is a method that returns the key to group by and the downstream collector collects all Stream elements grouped to the same key; in this case, for the values having the same key, we want to map the Stream element to the `Double` value ([`mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)) and collects those `Double` into a `List` ([`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--)).

The problem in your design is that your method takes a `Map<String, List<Double>> db` as parameter and mutates it when it is better to let the method return it.

```
public static Map<String, List<Double>> readFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
        return stream.skip(1)
                  .map(l -> l.split(","))
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    keys -> keys[1].replace("\"", ""),
                    Collectors.mapping(keys -> Double.valueOf(keys[2]), Collectors.toList())
                  ));
    }
}
```

Note that I also modified your code to let it throw the `IOException` instead of catching it doing nothing with it. If you want to handle that exception in the method itself, you can still add the catch part.

Comment: how do I still pass in my map into the method as used in my question? It seems to me that it is returning a stream but I want to capture that stream in the method as shown in this code fragment:
public static void ReadFile(String path, Map<String, List<Double>> db){}

Comment: @user200188 The method is returning the `Map<String, List<Double>>` that you used to have as parameter. (It is not returning a Stream).

Comment: Thanks alot. I just have a few questions:
1.Why do you think passing in the list as a parameter was an issue?
2.Could you please explain what is happening in the following statements:
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    keys -> keys[1].replace("\"", ""),
                    Collectors.mapping(keys -> Double.valueOf(keys[2]), Collectors.toList())

I honestly don't get it . I know what it is doing but how it is doing it is surprising.

Comment: @user200188 Because it's generally not a good idea to mutate a parameter given to a method when you can avoid it. And I added explanation for the collecting part.

Comment: Sorry, if I bother you but I am trying to understand how and where the code is checking for this condition in my method :
if(db.containsKey(keys[1])){
                List<Double> list = db.get(keys[1]);
                list.add(Double.valueOf(keys[2]));
                db.put(keys[1], list);
            }
            else{
                List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(Double.valueOf(keys[2]));
                db.put(keys[1],list);
            }

How does it know that the key exists or not and when to add elements to the list(the value part of the map

Comment: @user200188 This is all hidden inside the collector. And that's what it great (IMO). All those nasty details are factored inside the collector.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Stream API like this

```
Map<String, List<Double>> rows = Files.lines(Paths.get("file"))
        .skip(1)
        .map(s -> s.split("\"?,\"?"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[1], 
                 Collectors.mapping(s -> Double.parseDouble(s[2]), Collectors.toList())));
```

The main trick is skipping the first entry.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [BufferedReader.lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-), which returns a `Stream<String>` with the lines of the file. You could, at first instance, replace the I/O code with it:

```
try(Stream<String> fileLines = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))){
    fileLines.forEach(line -> {
        // Your code inside the "while" loop would go here
    });
}catch(IOException e){}
```

After this first transformation, you could rethink the structure of your "parsing" code to maybe put it into a more functional structure using operations such as "filter", "map" and the like.